# Prometheus change all nodenames to lowercase

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, azure-aks, prometheus-node-exporter

I've installed via Helm kube-prometheus-stack from prometheus-community repository. Everything works fine but I got a problem with node/host names.

I'm using AKS with one node pool and 8 nodes. An example node hostname is:
`aks-nodepool-0000A`. When I use command `kubectl get nodes` I can see that the node name is a little bit different because it's written in lowercase, for example `aks-nodepool-0000a`.

So that makes problem with metrics because some metrics are using lowercase node name like `kube_node_status_capacity{node="$node",resource="cpu"}` and other metrics are with uppercase last letter, for example this one: `node_uname_info{nodename="$node"})`.

This makes really a mess in my Grafana dashboards because I have to use two variables (one with lowercase and one with uppercase name).I tried to use case insensitive expression `kube_node_status_capacity{node=~"(?i:($node))"},resource="cpu"}` but it does not work in any query.

Is there a solution to change all `nodename` `node` values to lowercase?

Comment: How did you created cluster in AKS, using UI or CLI? You want to use default queries, not your own?

Comment: @PjoterS AFAIK it was created in UI (but not by me). I can use custom queries, but what's the difference? Sorry but I'm kinda beginner to Prometheus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long time ago I asked for it on GitHub. Few days ago I got answer. Now it can be easily done via `relabel_config`

GitHUb issue:
https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/discussions/792

Relabel_config:
https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#relabel_config